# Adding <form> tag in a column of wp_list_table

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, html-table

I have a html table that is built in a class that extends WP_List_Table. How can I wrap a column with `<form></form>` tag?

```
+-----+-----+--------+
| Foo | Bar | Action |
+-----+-----+--------+
| 1   | 2   | Click  |
+-----+-----+--------+
| 2   | 3   | Click  |
+-----+-----+--------+
| 3   | 4   | Click  |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

How can I wrap Click inside a `<form></form>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. A form can contain an entire table or be contained within a single table cell. It cannot contain part of a table.

Comment: Oh right. That's what I meant. Contained within a single table cell. How should I wrap it with <form> tag?

Comment: Yes. (And not put any forms in any of the cells since you cannot nest forms).

Comment: So what should be advisable then? Having the entire table wrap with <form> tag or single table cell are wrap with <form> tag?

Comment: It doesn't really matter unless you have other data in the form (and need to vary that data between cells or not)